# Unable to create the new dashboard : 404 messageDashboard not found

Tags: ansible, grafana

I am trying to  import a Grafana dashboard(JSON) to Grafana. Following is the ansible playbook

```
---
- name: task to parameterise grafana template
  hosts: localhost
  become: true
  user: root
  tasks:
    - name: Import Grafana dashboard
      grafana_dashboard:
        grafana_url: http://<host-ip>:3000
        state: present
        message: Updated by ansible
        uid: edO3sTlipu
        overwrite: yes
        path: "/home/centos/Kubernetes_cluster_monitoring.json"
```

And i am getting error below.

```
"msg": "error : Unable to create the new dashboard edO3sTlipu : 404 - {'status': 404, 'body': '{\"message\":\"Dashboard not found\",\"status\":\"not-found\"}', 'content-length': '54', 'url': 'http://13.235.2.156:3000/api/dashboards/db', 'expires': '-1', 'msg': 'HTTP Error 404: Not Found', 'connection': 'close', 'pragma': 'no-cache', 'cache-control': 'no-cache', 'date': 'Tue, 07 Jan 2020 08:38:46 GMT', 'x-frame-options': 'deny', 'content-type': 'application/json'}."
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this with help from here https://www.devopszones.com/2020/01/grafanadashboard-not-creating-new.html

> When your JSON file contain a id field, Grafana API will search for a
> dashboard with this id, and if it does not exists it return a 404.
> Hence delete this from your JSON file and run your playbook.